# Dialog element weird black background

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

Today I encountered a pretty strange and unusal problem and wanted to know if someone out there had already encountered it and if it's fixable. The problem is that, as you can see from my code right below here, I just have my Vue component with a dialog element from the Element-UI library. Nothing strange except that when I load the component up, the color behind the dialog goes from its normal greyish tone to a complete black and back to a greyish color. I know there should be an animation going from white to greyish and back to white when it disappears. I have placed my code right down here with two screenshots to make you understand better.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-dialog
      title="Choose a month to pre-load"
      :visible.sync="dialog"
      width="40%"
      center>
      <p>You can choose to load now the data you are going to use throughout the session. Just pick a month</p>
      <div class="block">
        <el-date-picker
          v-model="choosenMonth"
          type="month"
          placeholder="Pick a month">
        </el-date-picker>
      </div>
      <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button type="primary" @click="loadMonth()">Confirm</el-button>
      </span>
    </el-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dialog: true,
        choosenMonth: '',
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: Gif]

I have omitted the styles since I didn't even use them on the dialog. Also, as you can see I write both template, script and style in the same file as a component.

If someone has even the most remote idea please feel free to suggest something. Thanks a lot in advance!

### EDIT

I had added a gif instead of the two images since it represents better the situation.

Comment: Without looking your styles is hard to say, but probably you have a black background in somewhere. Here is an example of a vue modal where does the same  https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/mwLbw11k/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mwLbw11k

Comment: @VictorOliveira I have added a gif instead of the two images so maybe the problem is now more clear. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem that was causing this abnormal behaviour.

As you can see from the code above, I set the variable that holds the `:visible.sync` attribute immediatly in the return data() function to true. This is pretty wrong since the dialog at the time the variable is set, is still beeing rendered so it creates this messy black background. As a workaround to that I just set the varible to false to start with and set it to true in the `mounted` function.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      dialog : false,
      .....
      mounted: function() {
        this.dialog = true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: Working example]

This should solve any issue regarding strange behaviours. Hope this can help someone in the future. Cheers!

Comment: In my case I want to show it conditionally so when user's clicks on show then it appears but still it shows some black background

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around by adding a prop named modalAppendToBody = false. So, this will add the dialog with respect to parent container. Below is the snippet.

```
<el-dialog
        v-if="isInvite"
        :visible.sync="isInvite"
        :modalAppendToBody="false"
        >
        <h1>heelllooo</h1>
    </el-dialog>
```

Comment: This works for me. You can also use `:modal-append-to-body="false"` based on the documentation. https://element.eleme.io/2.4/#/en-US/component/dialog#attributes